# Trinitycore Question about APIs available for LUA scripts

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft, trinitycore

First of all, let me apologize if this is the wrong place to post this question.

I'm playing with the [Single Player Project server for 3.3.5](http://www.ac-web.org/forums/showthread.php?221383-Single-Player-Project-TC-R2). I'm trying to do a script that would teleport the player whenever the user points on the map inside the game.

I modified the [Carbonite addon](https://legacy-wow.com/wotlk-addons/Carbonite/) to add an item to the right-click menu of the map so it would send the gm command `[.go zonexy][3] [zonecoordinate X] [zonecoordinate Y]`.

This works very well with one snag, however. It only works for the player's current zone. I want it to work for all zones I can see on the map. For this, I need a zoneId located at the [AreaTableID](https://wow.gamepedia.com/AreaTableID). (Which is an optional argument to the .go zonexy command)

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to get the current map zoneid on the client side. I looked it up and only found [GetCurrentMapZone](https://wowwiki.fandom.com/wiki/API_GetCurrentMapZone)() which gives me a number that I don't really know what to do with. And [GetRealZoneText()](https://wowwiki.fandom.com/wiki/API_GetRealZoneText) which returns the zone name of where the cursor points in the map . Which is almost what I need. I need the zone ID and not the zone name. And [GetCurrentMapAreaID()](https://wow.gamepedia.com/API_GetCurrentMapAreaID) which also gives me a mapID but it doesn't match the zoneID i need.

So I thought to make a lua script on the server side that takes the [zonecoordinate X] [zonecoordinate Y] [zone name] from the client and converts the zone name to zone id. Or alternatively somehow figures out the zoneid from GetCurrentMapZone() and GetCurrentMapAreaID().

However, I didn't find any documentation of what APIs are available in the Lua script. I looked at some scripts that came along with the Single Player Project. One of them is 'System_Group_commands.lua'(Attached below) which I hooked up to. I successfully passed the information from the client but I don't know if it's possible to look up the string zone name and get it's id from the AreaTableID from LUA. Furthermore another problem is that I pass zone coordinates. Yet the 'Player: Teleport function in LUA wants absolute map coordinates. I looked at the c++ source code for the Teleport functions and for the '.go zonexy' function and it seems that the .go zonexy function converts the local coordinates to global coordinates. Using

```
Zone2MapCoordinates(x, y, zoneEntry->ID); //line 454 in cs_go.cpp attached below
```

However, I don't know if this function is exposed to the LUA scripts.

I would really appreciate if someone would help me out. Maybe there is an easy way to get the zone id from the client-side or something else that I'm missing...

Thank you

PS. A picture worth a 1000 words... [Here](https://youtu.be/4tenust9trI) is how this works so far. I would be great to extend it to other areas of the map.

[System_Group_commands.lua](https://pastebin.com/VvzikZ47) [cs_go.cpp](https://pastebin.com/RTuGPW6K)

Answer (score 0):

see WorldMapArea.dbc

mapid = ID + 1

Comment: Thankyou for finding this question after such a long time and attempt answering, but your answer is very short and I don't really understand what I should do from it.